# Trying to delete table row laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to delete table row by table cell ID.

I have a table called "server_admins". With table cell unique ID.

```
public function admins_delete($id)
{
    $serveradmins = DB::table('server_admins')->first();
    $serveradmins->delete($id);
    return Redirect::to("/admin/servers/admins");
}
```

**Route:**

```
ModuleRoute::post('admin/servers/admins/delete/{id}', 'AdminServersController@admins_delete');
```

**And my view:**

```
<a href="/admin/servers/admin/delete/{!! $serveradmin->id !!}"></a>
```

But does not work at all... Any info? I'm new with laravel, so im kind a noob on that :) Sorry for dumb ask and thanks for helping me understand laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Model::where('id',$id)->delete();; // Eloquent approach

DB::table('server_admins')->where('id',$id)->delete(); // Query Builder approach
```

Comment: Wow, relaly fast answer! Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly chain like this if you know the primary key of the model.

```
DB::table('server_admins')->destroy($id);
```

Another method is to call the delete method on after retrieving the model.

```
$admin = DB::table('server_admins')::find($id);
$admin->delete();
```